# Getting the current hour in C using time.h

Tags: c, time

Total newbie question here; I apologize in advance.

Suppose I have a daemon written in C that wakes itself up every five minutes or so, does some processing if there's anything in its input queue, and then goes back to sleep. Now suppose there is some processing that it only has to do after a certain (configurable) time--say, 2 pm (and before midnight).

In C, what is the quickest, best way to get the current time's hour into an int variable, so that it can easily be checked against--to determine if, in fact, it is after 2pm on today?

Comment: I assume you have good reason for wanting to implement this functionality on your own, but just in case, I thought I'd point out that this is basically what cron does.  Could your app simply be invoked by cron? (or scheduled tasks on windows)

Comment: The daemon has processing that it needs to do every time it wakes up, it just has some special processing that it does only after 2pm. Otherwise, yes, I would definitely agree that cron is the best solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

localtime.  See http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm_struct = localtime(&now);

int hour = tm_struct->tm_hour;
```

Comment: time_t rawtime;
time (&rawtime);
struct tm *tm_struct = localtime(&rawtime); was working for me

Answer (score 12):

The call `localtime(time(NULL))` will never work. The return value of `time()` is a `time_t`, and the first argument of localtime is a `time_t*`. Neither is the accepted answer, nor is the one with printf correct.

```
time_t now;
struct tm *now_tm;
int hour;

now = time(NULL);
now_tm = localtime(&now);
hour = now_tm->tm_hour;
```

Comment: I seem to recall the reason I accepted the first answer was because it was working for me. It might end up being platform-dependent? It's been 5 years and a different company since I looked at the code, so I really don't remember.

Answer (score 6):

```
printf("the hour is %d\n", localtime(time(NULL))->tm_hour);
```

This relies on the fact that `localtime()` returns a pointer to static storage.

Comment: This segfault on gcc 10.2.1, kernel 5.10.63.