# Current time in C

Tags: c, time

Edited....I got direction from @pablo1977 where to code and compile the codes online. Thanks.
Sorry I got to edit this question to prevent further down vote.

Comment: The argument is supposed to be a pointer to a time_t object to hold the result. If the argument is null, the value is returned. If an invalid-pointer is passed the results are undefined.

Comment: You can do experiments in [ideone](http://ideone.com). There you can compile and run programs.

Comment: A C compile will *not* tell you UB.

Comment: Run (or search) `man 2 time` for this function's manual.

Comment: @pablo1977 thanks a lot. At least you show me some directions where to go if I don't have the compiler. Not just like those who gave me down vote :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

time(..) function with NULL input argument, will return the number of seconds from January 1, 1970

time(time_t*) type
So input argument 0 is consider as NULL.
But 1 will generate error.
Input must be a time_t* type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t seconds;

  seconds = time (NULL);
  printf ("%ld hours since January 1, 1970", seconds/3600);

  return 0;
}
```

For more see [Getting the current hour in C using time.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701524/getting-the-current-hour-in-c-using-time-h?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The signature is

```
time_t time( time_t *tp )
```

tp is the address of the time_t in which the value is returned. However, it can be null (0), in which case it is not used.