# Read system time in C with time header

Tags: c, time, esp32, time.h, time-t

I am running a c program for esp32 microcontroller devkit. And i am trying to get localtime from system using time.h

so i am using this code

```
time_t curTime;
time(&curTime);
printf("%s\n",ctime(&curTime));
struct tm *myTime=localtime(&curTime);
```

Which prints:

```
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
```

What do i miss ?
I read 
[Getting the current hour in C using time.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701524/getting-the-current-hour-in-c-using-time-h)

but there is not difference and my debian system, and eclipse does not want to cooperate.

Comment: You're doing it right. The microcontroller probably doesn't have a calendar clock chip, so it doesn't know the time.

Comment: what i am writing is before i send anything to controller. it is just in c program and i am printing it before i write it. Controller gets this time and sends it to rtc properly and continues from 1970

Comment: Oh, I thought you were running this code on the microcontroller.

Comment: no it is before so i can set the rtc to the current time and my debian system does not act as i was expecting.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "eclipse does not want to cooperate"?

Comment: just a joke, i do not know what is the problem and why on prinf  i get 1970 and not current time. is it possibe to be a problem o the xtensa compiler that esp32 uses?

Comment: Dear Barmar i create a new project in a new eclipse instance that is clean, started a new c program and it worked properly. So i expect that setup of eclipse toolchain with xtensa compiler brings the problem.

Comment: The formatted result you see is what you get when you convert 0 time to a string in the UTC time zone.  So `time()` is probably returning zero.

Comment: yes in know and agree that this is the initial and somehow the function is not ok. But it is about the specific compiler i think